# how do I know if a page is pushed or not in navigation stack?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

let say I have 2 pages, PageA and PageB.

if a user tap a button in PageA then it will move to PageB using the code below

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("pageB");
```

so as a result, there is back button in the top left app bar in PageB

my question is .....

how do I know if a page is pushed or not? I want to do something only if there is a back button in the appbar in a page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```dart
final hasPagePushed = Navigator.of(context).canPop();
```

This is actually what the flutter's `AppBar` is using to know whether or not it should display the back button.